# Create a generic button click event for all buttons?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

**Goal:** Instead of coding 64 buttonX_clicked() events I would like to code a single buttonHandler() that is called when any button is clicked and uses the button's parsed position to take the according action.

[image: UserControl1.cs]

**Background:** I am learning how to use .NET Forms in C# and am working on a basic chess app. My current UI is shown above, it uses 64 individual buttons with one for each board position. I currently use a relatively ugly loop to store all my buttons in an array and then assign them a starting value according to their position.

**Sidenote:** If the only solution is to code every buttonX_clicked() to call the buttonHandler() then an effecient way to do that in Visual Studio is also appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Chess_Test
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        // pawn , knight, bishop, rook, queen, king
        //   1  ,   2   ,   3   ,   4 ,   5  ,  6
        public int[,] nboard = new int[8, 8] {
            { 4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 3, 2, 4 },
            { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
            { 4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 3, 2, 4 }
        };

        Button[] bboard = new Button[64];

        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            int i = 0;
            string init = "4235632411111111000000000000000000000000000000001111111142356324";
            foreach (var button in chessPanel.Controls.OfType<Button>())
            {
                if (!button.Name.Contains("usr"))
                {
                    string parsed = Regex.Replace(button.Name, @"[^\d]+", "").Trim();
                    int num = int.Parse(parsed) - 1;
                    bboard[num] = button;
                    button.Text = init[num].ToString();
                }
            }

        }

        private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `button.Click += button1_Click;` to your loop. In the click event, cast the `sender` as a button and examine the button name to know which button was clicked.

Comment: Adding to what @LarsTech said. This is a pretty common solution, usually using the name to decide which button, sometimes the text (consider, for example a simple calculator app). Consider doing the cast like this: `if (sender is Button btn) { /* handle the button btn */ }`

Comment: Have you tried something like `foreach (var b in bbutton) b.Click += buttonHandler;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the row col information of your button in the 'button.Tag' property as a Tuple and add a single 'button_Click' handler to every button.

On the event you read the Tuple and get the position.

```
{
    if (!button.Name.Contains("usr"))
    {            
        string parsed = Regex.Replace(button.Name, @"[^\d]+", "").Trim();
        int position = int.Parse(parsed) - 1;

         // if % operation = 0, return col 7, otherwise position - 1
        int col = (num % 8) == 0 ? 7 : (num % 8) - 1;

        // if / operation = 8, return row 7, otherwise num / 8
        int row = (num % 8) == 0 ? (num / 8) - 1 : (num / 8); 

        // Add row,col to tag
        button.Tag = new Tuple<int, int>(row, col);
        button.Text = init[position].ToString();

        // Add the handler here
        button.Click += button_Click; 
    }
}      
  
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    // Get the clicked button
    Button button = (Button)sender;

    // Read the position from the buttons Tag
    Tuple<int, int> position = (Tuple<int, int>)button.Tag;

    // Extract the row and col
    int row = position.Item1;
    int col = position.Item2;

    // get the figure from your array by row / col
    int figure = nboard[row, col];
   
    // ...        

}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! After testing some of the answers above I was just starting to investigate the 'tags' feature and you beat me to it.